# Flask unresponsive while uploading file or waiting for other server

Tags: python, flask

My Flask stops responding when uploading files or when collecting data from another server via GET.  I assume, the problem is, that Flask is only running on one thread.

How can I change this, so multiple users can use the site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flask's development webserver (invoked when you use `app.run`) is not a production web server.

Quoting the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/):

> You can use the builtin server during development, but you should use a full deployment option for production applications. (Do not use the builtin development server in production.)

If you want to use Flask in a production environment take a look at the [deployment options](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/) suggested by the documentation.

For *testing purposes* with small applications that are doing slightly complicated things I deploy the code I'm developing behind CherryPy [using this snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/24/).  (The only disadvantage of this pattern is you loose access to Werkzeug's debugger.)